# Multivariate Similarity Metrics

Tags: math, statistics, probability

Say I am tracking 2 objects moving in space & time,

- I know their x,y co-ords and score (score being a probabilistic
  measure of the tracked being the actual object),
- and  I get several
  such {x,y,score} samples over time for each object

What metric would I use to measure "similarity" of say a ball moving across a room vs. man moving across the room vs. a child moving across the room.

Assume the score is pretty accurate.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you mean by "similarity".  Are you talking about capturing imagery from a camera?

Comment: Thanks, it was based on proximity sensors, but you could think of it as a camera if that helps. But AFAIK, should not make a difference. This was more of a stats question.

Comment: For example, if the variables were location, education, income over time i.e .a multivariate time-series. How should I calculate pairwise similarity between sample sets? I don't think a Linear Regression would help, or would it?

Comment: So you're looking at how to discriminate between the tracks the two target types create?

Comment: That, and can you post some sample data?

Comment: @andand thanks for responding. I am looking to discriminate. Unfortunately, I don't have data to share. Would it be too hard to answer without data? Establish similarity between multivariate time series?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3670/discussion-between-mikos-and-andand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description, I'd recommend looking into a [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or possibly an [artificial neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) or some other [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) approach.  However, there are a number of [other techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(mathematics)) that might be more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: The way I approached was to use a combination of Logistic Regression and Partial Least Squares Method. HTH.